# Convert command doesn't respect order

Tags: convert, animations

I've got a certain number of png files, named `1.png`, `2.png`, etc. and need to make an animation with them.
I'm using `convert -delay 20 *.png animation.gif`.

The first time I used it, it happened that the animation created started at 10 then 11 then 12, all the way up to 19 and then it goes to 2! It's logical, but I don't want that. So what I did was modify the names to `01.png`, `02.png`.

That was OK at the beginning. Now, I want to make a gif with more images(thousands), and the problem is that when it goes 10 for example, it goes to 100! I can't be modifying the names manually, because all this is part of a script, and the user chooses how many png he wants. So, how to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the `convert` command - your shell is expanding the glob pattern `*.png` before it is passed to the command, and it does so in the lexical collation order `LC_COLLATE` defined as part of system's current `locale`.

Unfortunately it's hard to get numeric ordering in the bash shell (which is what I assume you are using): if you don't mind switching to `zsh` there is the possibility to use a numeric [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) i.e.

```
convert -delay 20 *.png(n) animation.gif
```

For further discussion, see for example this related Q&A [Glob with Numerical Order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/glob-with-numerical-order)